# How to avoid casting instance class type?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typescript-generics

I want to create a properly typed function which receives an argument with a service name and returns an instance of that service. I cannot achieve the result without casting the instance.

Better explained with a simplified example:

```
class ECR {
    public image(): void {}
}

class ECS {
    public cluster(): void {}
}

const aws = {
    ECR,
    ECS
};

type Aws = {
    ECR: ECR
    ECS: ECS
}

function createService<T extends 'ECR' | 'ECS'>( serviceName: T, aws: typeof AWS ): Aws[T] {
    const Constr = aws[ serviceName ];

    const f: Aws[T] = new Constr(); // here I receive the error if do not cast it 'as Aws[T]'

    return f;
}
```

Error:

```
Type 'ECR | ECS' is not assignable to type 'Aws[T]'.
  Type 'ECR' is not assignable to type 'Aws[T]'.
    Type 'ECR' is not assignable to type 'ECR & ECS'.
      Property 'cluster' is missing in type 'ECR' but required in type 'ECS'.
```

Any idea how to properly type this function without the need of casting?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
type MapToConstructor<T> = { [K in keyof T]: new () => T[K] };

function createService<T extends 'ECR' | 'ECS', U extends Aws = Aws>(
  serviceName: T,
  aws: MapToConstructor<U>
): U[T] {
    const Constr = aws[ serviceName ];
    const f = new Constr();
    return f;
}
```

([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiDCAlaBvAsAKGt6AHArgEYgCWw0JAtmAOYCmAFAJQBc0AbgPYkAmqAvpkEZMoSDAQBlVJhx4ipcqHwQALnQBOzNl14ChmUZwB2a6GADuMALwysOBIgA0sh-ElCA3IYyqAnrh00ACCVtC26PbYjmyOrtHuse4GIr4BQQCyYLgAKpzwJmoa+MCqnBoAPDkAfOGo0ADaANIUxtAA1nR+nABm0DkAumzGdBbQzOG1Oc0D0PzeqT34xqUkJtDAGnRg6pKa7GR0VdB0AB7qxjwwAOSO19AAPtC37tdO0ACqJ+d0lzChNhCVmqDGgEH2hwAcmBKHQ2Dl3pYIGwsrl8oVVMVSuUKh9aqxPg1BnY5MAMdACqZMXUkQ0wRDgHRobDoAMFqTyX1bCMxpSisx2Tgtqp8Bo2j0FsJMEsVqo1m1jJxVAB1crtEjGGjHM4XK7PO6PfWvEH0jQHRnMuH9RFWFHZPJ8zElMqVAH4tgAomzSIcqkUjEaGlWOngs1QmFBNnxDacuo8-1UrRMQXYYWi8WSzBAA))

I'm not entirely why this works, but I think it's something to do with TS deferring the evaluation of the type of `Constr` due to the generic. In the working example above, hovering over `Constr` in `new Constr()` shows that its type is `new () => U[T]`, but doing the same in the below code shows `new () => ECR | ECS`.

```
function notWorking<T extends 'ECR' | 'ECS'>(
  serviceName: T,
  aws: MapToConstructor<Aws>
): Aws[T] {
    const Constr = aws[ serviceName ];
    const f = new Constr();
    return f;
}
```